# Jooq code generator warns 'ignroing foreign key'

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I used this script to generate a schema

```sql
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS test_schema CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA test_schema;
SET search_path TO test_schema;

CREATE TABLE accounts
(
  user_id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name            TEXT      NOT NULL,
  user_email           TEXT      NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (user_name),
  UNIQUE (user_email)
);

CREATE TABLE sessions
(
  session_id          TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id             INT4      NOT NULL REFERENCES accounts (user_id),
  session_created_at  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
  session_deleted_at  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 'infinity'
);
```

Then I configured the code generator with this schema.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
    <jdbc>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:7777/mydb</url>
        <user>username</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
            <inputSchema>test_schema</inputSchema>
        </database>

        <generate>
        </generate>

        <target>
            <packageName>com.jooq.gen</packageName>
            <directory>../gen</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

After running the code generator from the command line, I noticed this warning message

```log
Apr 01, 2016 11:48:47 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Adding foreign key       : sessions__sessions_user_id_fkey (test_schema.sessions.user_id) referencing accounts_pkey
Apr 01, 2016 11:48:47 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger warn
WARNING: Ignoring foreign key     : sessions__sessions_user_id_fkey (test_schema.sessions.user_id) referencing accounts_pkey references a schema out of scope for jooq-meta: null
Apr 01, 2016 11:48:47 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger warn
WARNING: Ignoring foreign key     : sessions__sessions_user_id_fkey (test_schema.sessions.user_id) referencing accounts_pkey references a schema out of scope for jooq-meta: null
```

While I **DON'T** have any problem so far using the generated java classes, I would like to know why jooq generator sent out this warning and what is the consequence due to the ignoring of foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that with database designs that extend over multiple schemas, setting up the code generator not to generate all such schemas might be a mistake, and users should be made aware of this. Without the other schema being in scope for the code generator, foreign key navigational methods (such as `SessionsRecord.fetchParent(SESSIONS_USER_ID_FKEY)`) will not be possible.

That's it. So, you can safely ignore that message. The log level might be [a bit excessive](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5186).